# I need to rename all image files in a directory, and name them whatever the folder they are in is called

Tags: bash, unix

I need to rename all image files in a directory, and name them whatever the folder they are in is called... Is this possible using a Bash script?

I also need to number them (0001.jpg, 0002.jpg, 0003.jpg, ect...) consecutively. The problem I'm having is that there are some jumps between the numbers.. (0018.jpg, 0019.jpg, 0025.jpg, 0026.jpg, ect...) I'd like to rename the 0025.jpg to be 0020.jpg and the 0026.jpg to be 0021.jpg ect...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can use `find /search/path -type d` to find all dirs and use -exec option to exec some actions with directory path as parameter. And you can have bash script which runs `NUM=0; for file in /path/to/folder/*.jpg; do mv file NUM.jpg; let "NUM=NUM+1"; done;` or something like this

Answer (score 0):

To use this command you have to be in the directory where the .jpg files are or you have to customize the command a little bit.

```
 let a=0; for i in *.jpg; do let a=a+1; b=`basename $PWD`; c=`printf %04d$b.jpg $a`; mv $i $c; done
```

The output will look like:

```
0001<dirname>.jpg
```